# Scilab - Atoms - how to use it?

Tags: scilab

I am new to Scilab. I want to cluster a dataset. I installed the external module 'CLUSTER' & also loaded it. Unfortunately, I don't know how to use it. I can find the description of the module but I could not find how to call it and use it.

Could you please tell me how I can use the atoms module?

Comment: With "_I can find the description of the module_", do you mean the help files? The clusters toolbox provides some examples for its usage.

Answer (score 0):

Its help can be entered by calling help for one of its functions, for instance

```
--> help CMeans
```

Then you can get the module's summary and navigate through its pages with the help path at the top of each page. There are runable examples in the pages.